# Use a keyboard shortcut to switch between synergy-"ized" monitors/windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, synergy, window-switching

Is it possible to map a command to my keyboard so that I can switch between my various windows?

I checked on the synergy website but was not able to find very much about the subject. I'm trying to be able to essentially alt+tab and cycle through all the applications I have running on all my computers.

It's not necessary that all windows show up on the main screen but I'd like to be able to shift focus to a different window without having to move my mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has turned out to be remarkably simple. I'll provide my configuration file as an example:

```
section: screens
    optiplex-380:
    laptop:
    hp7:
end
section: links
    optiplex-380:
        left = laptop
        right = hp7
    laptop:
        right = optiplex-380
    hp7:
        left = optiplex-380
end
section: options
    keystroke(alt+right)      = switchToScreen(hp7)
    keystroke(alt+down)       = switchToScreen(optiplex-380)
    keystroke(alt+left)       = switchToScreen(laptop)
end
```

As you can see the addition of the "section: options" with a keystroke and the switchToScreen function seems to be the ticket here.